# passing tableview offset data to tableview cell using delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I don't know why but delegates have always hurt my brain.

I have the delegate like so:

```
protocol StylistControllerDelegate {
    func userInteractsWithTableView(tableViewOffset: CGFloat)
}
```

It sits inside StylistController and is called when the user scrolls:

```
class StylistController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var delegate : StylistControllerDelegate?

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    self.delegate?.userInteractsWithTableView(tableViewOffset: offset)
}
```

inside the cell I am attempting to set the CGFloat value to a variable:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, StylistControllerDelegate {

    //var stylistControllerTableViewOffset: CGFloat?

    func userInteractsWithTableView(tableViewOffset: CGFloat) {
        print(tableViewOffset)
        if tableViewOffset > 100 {
            collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        } else {
            collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

I use the offset to enable and disable to ability to scroll of the collectionview INSIDE the cell. Once it gets to a certain value (in this case 100), the ability to scroll is enabled.

Comment: What's the problem? Is it not working? Does it crash?

Comment: I've edited my question a little to explain what I'm attempting.  It's just that, nothing happens.

Comment: and have you actually set this delegate property? Try tos et a breakpoint on line containing and see how it's executed `self.delegate?.userInteractsWithTableView(tableViewOffset: offset)`

Comment: Yeah that runs fine and hits the line of code.

Comment: What's the value of `self.delegate` when it gets there?

Comment: Did you set delegate value in `CollectionViewCell` ?

Comment: not sure what you're asking, but `print(tableViewOffset)` never gets called/printed. I've set the delegate function inside `CollectionViewCell`

Comment: try to share a gist or a little poc on github, it would be easier to debug